# How can I run unzip silently in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zip

I have a lot of Zip archives that I want to unpack in a script. Is there any way to run them silently?

Here is what I have:

```
bash> unzip  02b852e3571e46f25fdfc79f43ceb726ddff9ba7.zip 
Archive:  02b852e3571e46f25fdfc79f43ceb726ddff9ba7.zip
02b852e3571e46f25fdfc79f43ceb726ddff9ba7
  inflating: .editorconfig           
  inflating: .gitattributes      
bash>
```

Here is what I want:

```
bash> unzip <something to silence zip> MyArchive.zip      
bash>
```

Comment: `man unzip` is your friend (works for more or less all commands you can run in Terminal)

Comment: I know about `man` but I believe most people will agree it is difficult to find what you want looking through `man` pages. I think it was faster and easier to ask here.

Comment: It takes some time tontet used to it, but things like command line options are easy to be found there.

Comment: Asking here is a lot more effort than using `man command`. But googling and jumping to the best answer *after* this has been asked *is* easier than using `man`. So bless this guy for asking.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

As stated in the manual, -q (quiet) or -qq (even quieter).

```
unzip -qq filename
```

Comment: A link to the manual with a quote of the relevant part would be great

Answer (score 7):

If you don’t want to see the output from your terminal commands then you can redirect both standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` by adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end of your command.  Of course, this can hide errors, so you might want to redirect it to a file instead, depending on your use case.